# Apache atlas UI not showing up

Tags: java, solr, hbase, janusgraph, apache-atlas

I am trying to install apache atlas from source. I have cloned the repo from https://github.com/apache/atlas and built the source and then packaged it using `mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist`.

I have local installations of HBase and solr running under http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ and http://localhost:16010/master-status respectively.

I am running a ubuntu-22.10 under a VM Virtuabox from a windows10 machine

However, when I try to run the atlas_start.py it says

```
Starting Atlas server on host: localhost
Starting Atlas server on port: 21000
................................................................................................
Apache Atlas Server started!!!
```

But the localhost:21000 gives a 503 service unavailable.

I am adding my atlas-application.properties from ~/atlas/conf

```
#########  Graph Database Configs  #########

# Graph Database

#Configures the graph database to use.  Defaults to JanusGraph
#atlas.graphdb.backend=org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase

# Graph Storage
# Set atlas.graph.storage.backend to the correct value for your desired storage
# backend. Possible values:
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/
atlas.graph.index.backend=solr
#
# hbase
# cassandra
# embeddedcassandra - Should only be set by building Atlas with  -Pdist,embedded-cassandra-solr
# berkeleyje
#
# See the configuration documentation for more information about configuring the various  storage backends.
#
atlas.graph.storage.backend=hbase2
atlas.graph.storage.hostname=localhost
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.table=atlas_janus
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.create-table=true
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.table-prefix=atlas_


atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=60000
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=60000

atlas.server.bind.address=0.0.0.0
atlas.server.https.enabled=false
atlas.server.metrics.enabled=false
atlas.server.metrics.graphite.enabled=false
atlas.server.metrics.graphite.server=localhost
atlas.server.metrics.graphite.port=2003
atlas.server.metrics.graphite.prefix=atlas

#Hbase
#For standalone mode , specify localhost
#for distributed mode, specify zookeeper quorum here
atlas.graph.storage.hostname=
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.regions-per-server=1

#In order to use Cassandra as a backend, comment out the hbase specific properties above, and uncomment the
#the following properties
#atlas.graph.storage.clustername=
#atlas.graph.storage.port=

# Gremlin Query Optimizer
#
# Enables rewriting gremlin queries to maximize performance. This flag is provided as
# a possible way to work around any defects that are found in the optimizer until they
# are resolved.
#atlas.query.gremlinOptimizerEnabled=true

# Delete handler
#
# This allows the default behavior of doing "soft" deletes to be changed.
#
# Allowed Values:
# org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.SoftDeleteHandlerV1 - all deletes are "soft" deletes
# org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.HardDeleteHandlerV1 - all deletes are "hard" deletes
#
#atlas.DeleteHandlerV1.impl=org.apache.atlas.repository.store.graph.v1.SoftDeleteHandlerV1

# Entity audit repository
#
# This allows the default behavior of logging entity changes to hbase to be changed.
#
# Allowed Values:
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.HBaseBasedAuditRepository - log entity changes to hbase
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.CassandraBasedAuditRepository - log entity changes to cassandra
# org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.NoopEntityAuditRepository - disable the audit repository
#
atlas.EntityAuditRepository.impl=org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.HBaseBasedAuditRepository

# if Cassandra is used as a backend for audit from the above property, uncomment and set the following
# properties appropriately. If using the embedded cassandra profile, these properties can remain
# commented out.
# atlas.EntityAuditRepository.keyspace=atlas_audit
# atlas.EntityAuditRepository.replicationFactor=1

# Graph Search Index
atlas.graph.index.search.backend=solr

# Use embedded Solr server
#atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=embedded

# Solr home directory (where Solr configuration files are located)
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.home=/usr/local/solr-9.5.0

# Solr data directory (where Solr indexes are stored)
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.data.dir=/opt/solr/example

# Number of Solr server threads
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.threads=1

# Port for the embedded Solr server
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.http.port=8983

#Solr
#Solr cloud mode properties
#atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=cloud
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-connect-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-session-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher=false

#Solr http mode properties
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=http
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:8983/solr

# ElasticSearch support (Tech Preview)
# Comment out above solr configuration, and uncomment the following two lines. Additionally, make sure the
# hostname field is set to a comma delimited set of elasticsearch master nodes, or an ELB that fronts the masters.
#
# Elasticsearch does not provide authentication out of the box, but does provide an option with the X-Pack product
# https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/security
#
# Alternatively, the JanusGraph documentation provides some tips on how to secure Elasticsearch without additional
# plugins: https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/elasticsearch.html
#atlas.graph.index.search.hostname=localhost
#atlas.graph.index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true

# Solr-specific configuration property
atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size=150

#########  Import Configs  #########
#atlas.import.temp.directory=/temp/import

#########  Notification Configs  #########
atlas.notification.embedded=true
atlas.kafka.data=${sys:atlas.home}/data/kafka
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:9026
atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9027
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=400
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=200
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.sync.time.ms=20
atlas.kafka.auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
atlas.kafka.hook.group.id=atlas

atlas.kafka.enable.auto.commit=false
atlas.kafka.auto.offset.reset=earliest
atlas.kafka.session.timeout.ms=30000
atlas.kafka.offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
atlas.kafka.poll.timeout.ms=1000

atlas.notification.create.topics=true
atlas.notification.replicas=1
atlas.notification.topics=ATLAS_HOOK,ATLAS_ENTITIES
atlas.notification.log.failed.messages=true
atlas.notification.consumer.retry.interval=500
atlas.notification.hook.retry.interval=1000
# Enable for Kerberized Kafka clusters
#atlas.notification.kafka.service.principal=kafka/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM
#atlas.notification.kafka.keytab.location=/etc/security/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab

## Server port configuration
atlas.server.http.port=21000
atlas.server.https.port=21443

#########  Security Properties  #########

# SSL config
atlas.enableTLS=false

#truststore.file=/path/to/truststore.jks
#cert.stores.credential.provider.path=jceks://file/path/to/credentialstore.jceks

#following only required for 2-way SSL
#keystore.file=/path/to/keystore.jks

# Authentication config

atlas.authentication.method.kerberos=false
atlas.authentication.method.file=true

#### ldap.type= LDAP or AD
atlas.authentication.method.ldap.type=none

#### user credentials file
atlas.authentication.method.file.filename=${sys:atlas.home}/conf/users-credentials.properties

### groups from UGI
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ugi-groups=true

######## LDAP properties #########
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.url=ldap://<ldap server url>:389
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.userDNpattern=uid={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupSearchBase=dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupSearchFilter=(member=uid={0},ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com)
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.groupRoleAttribute=cn
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.base.dn=dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.bind.dn=cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.bind.password=<password>
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.referral=ignore
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.user.searchfilter=(uid={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.default.role=<default role>


######### Active directory properties #######
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.domain=example.com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.url=ldap://<AD server url>:389
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.base.dn=(sAMAccountName={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.bind.dn=CN=team,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.bind.password=<password>
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.referral=ignore
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.user.searchfilter=(sAMAccountName={0})
#atlas.authentication.method.ldap.ad.default.role=<default role>

#########  JAAS Configuration ########

#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.loginModuleName = com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.loginModuleControlFlag = required
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.useKeyTab = true
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.storeKey = true
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.serviceName = kafka
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.keyTab = /etc/security/keytabs/atlas.service.keytab
#atlas.jaas.KafkaClient.option.principal = atlas/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM

#########  Server Properties  #########
atlas.rest.address=http://localhost:21000
# If enabled and set to true, this will run setup steps when the server starts
#atlas.server.run.setup.on.start=false

#########  Entity Audit Configs  #########
atlas.audit.hbase.tablename=apache_atlas_entity_audit
atlas.audit.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=1000
atlas.audit.hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost:2181

#########  High Availability Configuration ########
atlas.server.ha.enabled=false
#### Enabled the configs below as per need if HA is enabled #####
#atlas.server.ids=id1
#atlas.server.address.id1=localhost:21000
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.retry.sleeptime.ms=1000
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.num.retries=3
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=20000
## if ACLs need to be set on the created nodes, uncomment these lines and set the values ##
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.acl=<scheme>:<id>
#atlas.server.ha.zookeeper.auth=<scheme>:<authinfo>



######### Atlas Authorization #########
atlas.authorizer.impl=simple
atlas.authorizer.simple.authz.policy.file=atlas-simple-authz-policy.json

#########  Type Cache Implementation ########
# A type cache class which implements
# org.apache.atlas.typesystem.types.cache.TypeCache.
# The default implementation is org.apache.atlas.typesystem.types.cache.DefaultTypeCache which is a local in-memory type cache.
#atlas.TypeCache.impl=

#########  Performance Configs  #########
#atlas.graph.storage.lock.retries=10
#atlas.graph.storage.cache.db-cache-time=120000

#########  CSRF Configs  #########
atlas.rest-csrf.enabled=true
atlas.rest-csrf.browser-useragents-regex=^Mozilla.*,^Opera.*,^Chrome.*
atlas.rest-csrf.methods-to-ignore=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,TRACE
atlas.rest-csrf.custom-header=X-XSRF-HEADER

############ KNOX Configs ################
#atlas.sso.knox.browser.useragent=Mozilla,Chrome,Opera
#atlas.sso.knox.enabled=true
#atlas.sso.knox.providerurl=https://<knox gateway ip>:8443/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso
#atlas.sso.knox.publicKey=

############ Atlas Metric/Stats configs ################
# Format: atlas.metric.query.<key>.<name>
atlas.metric.query.cache.ttlInSecs=900
#atlas.metric.query.general.typeCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.typeUnusedCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.entityCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.tagCount=
#atlas.metric.query.general.entityDeleted=
#
#atlas.metric.query.entity.typeEntities=
#atlas.metric.query.entity.entityTagged=
#
#atlas.metric.query.tags.entityTags=

#########  Compiled Query Cache Configuration  #########

# The size of the compiled query cache.  Older queries will be evicted from the cache
# when we reach the capacity.

#atlas.CompiledQueryCache.capacity=1000

# Allows notifications when items are evicted from the compiled query
# cache because it has become full.  A warning will be issued when
# the specified number of evictions have occurred.  If the eviction
# warning threshold <= 0, no eviction warnings will be issued.

#atlas.CompiledQueryCache.evictionWarningThrottle=0


#########  Full Text Search Configuration  #########

#Set to false to disable full text search.
#atlas.search.fulltext.enable=true

#########  Gremlin Search Configuration  #########

#Set to false to disable gremlin search.
atlas.search.gremlin.enable=false


########## Add http headers ###########

#atlas.headers.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
#atlas.headers.Access-Control-Allow-Methods=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,POST
#atlas.headers.<headerName>=<headerValue>


#########  UI Configuration ########

#atlas.ui.default.version=v2

######### Skip check for the same attribute name in Parent type and Child type #########

#atlas.skip.check.for.parent.child.attribute.name=true
```

The start up fails with the following error from application.log file :

```
2024-03-28 18:20:27,028 INFO  - [main:] ~ Tx Log-based Index Recovery: Enabled! (AtlasJanusGraphDatabase:246)
2024-03-28 18:20:27,224 WARN  - [main:] ~ Local setting index.search.solr.mode=http (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (cloud,http).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting. (ReadConfigurationBuilder:284)
2024-03-28 18:20:27,273 WARN  - [main:] ~ org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Krb5HttpClientBuilder is configured without specifying system property 'java.security.auth.login.config' (Krb5HttpClientBuilder:190)
2024-03-28 18:20:27,273 WARN  - [main:] ~ Failed to obtain graph instance on attempt 3 of 3 (AtlasGraphProvider:118)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.Solr6Index
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:79)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:527)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:511)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:239)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1355)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:184)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:176)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:147)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.initJanusGraph(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:219)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.getGraphInstance(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:203)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graphdb.janus.AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.getGraph(AtlasJanusGraphDatabase.java:369)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider.getGraphInstance(AtlasGraphProvider.java:52)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider.retry(AtlasGraphProvider.java:114)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider.get(AtlasGraphProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48bbd3d1.CGLIB$get$0(<generated>)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48bbd3d1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$708375fa.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.apache.atlas.repository.graph.AtlasGraphProvider$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48bbd3d1.get(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.atlas.web.setup.KerberosAwareListener.contextInitialized(KerberosAwareListener.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.apache.atlas.web.service.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:110)
    at org.apache.atlas.Atlas.main(Atlas.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:73)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized mode: cloud,http
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.Solr6Index$Mode.parse(Solr6Index.java:153)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.Solr6Index.<init>(Solr6Index.java:192)
    ... 105 more
2024-03-28 18:20:27,274 INFO  - [main:] ~ Max retries exceeded. (AtlasGraphProvider:121)
```

Would be of great help if someone could provide which way I must look to fix this. I have tried multiple ways to install this and has been stuck for days.

Comment: You set `atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=http` in your config, and the first warning says _"Local setting index.search.solr.mode=http (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (cloud,http)_", and the error is indeed "_Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized mode: cloud,http_". The warning also suggests to "_Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting._".

Comment: Hi @EricLavault, any idea how I could resolve this? Do i not set this property in my atlas-application.properties and let the globally managed value take over? But that would cause the same error wouldn't it if it tries to override the value with cloud, http?

Also how to use the  ManagementSystem interface to control this setting? Could you please provide a bit more light into this?

Comment: Your local setting for solr mode (http) is already overridden by the globally managed value (cloud,http) which is wrong, it should be either http or cloud. You need to set mode=http at the global level using the management API (using the gremlin console I think). See [JanusGraph Global Configuration](https://docs.janusgraph.org/configs/#global-configuration) (I'm not a janusgraph expert and I don't think I can provide a full answer).

Comment: Also in the config there is this line `atlas.graph.storage.hostname=` which probably overrides (as it comes after) this one `atlas.graph.storage.hostname=localhost`.

Comment: Pleas sort your configs, also for your own night rest